# How can I split up operands but keep the options together, in a wrapper script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments

I'm writing a wrapper that will call a command for each operand, but with the same options. For example

```
wrapper -i foo bar
```

calls the wrapped command as

```
wrapped -i foo
wrapped -i bar
```

As well, if there are no operands, it should call the wrapped command just once with the options, e.g. `wrapper -h` → `wrapped -h`.

The command takes GNU-style short and long options, so for example `-i` and `--input`, and `--` to indicate the end of options.

I've considered using `argparse`, but I would have to make it aware of all the options the command takes, which would be a huge pain.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over `sys.argv` and pop any arguments that start with a dash `-` into another list, and break if the argument is a double-dash `--`.

```
args = sys.argv[1:]
options = []

for arg in args[:]:
    if arg.startswith('-'):
        options.append(args.pop(0))
        if arg == '--':
            break
```

Then iterate over the operands, passing the options to the command on each call. Though if there are no operands, call it with just the options.

```
for arg in args:
    command(options, arg)
if not args:
    command(options)
```

How you define `command` is up to you.